# What's the cause of java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in my situation

Tags: java, visual-studio, java-native-interface

I build a dll with Visual Studio 2008 and it's called by java side throuth jni.
It works fine in A machine but failed in B machine. 
The error info is like:
**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:xxx.dll Can't find dependent libraries**

The configuration info is like below (The OS and jdk is the same):

A machine:

- Win7 64bit;
- java version "1.7.0_21" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
  Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
- eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64

B machine:

- Win7 64bit;
- java version "1.7.0_65" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_65-b19)
  Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
- eclipse-java-luna-SR1a-win32

The **code generation** of dll is **Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)**.

I have no idea about the cause so that please let me know if you need more information to judge the cause.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Most likely you are missing the MSVC2008 runtime library

Comment: @MarkRotteveel. Thanks. But what should I do to install it in a light way? No need to install VS 2008 on B machine. Right?^_^

Comment: Assuming this is the actual problem, you of course don't need to install visual studio, you only need to install the runtime library, eg [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582) or [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The   **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:xxx.dll Can't find dependent libraries** is throwed in B machine but not in A machine is because that dll's dependent libraries can't be found by the dll in B machine and to fix it, you can add dependent libraries' path to the environment path. To get the dependent libraries, follow @SubOptimal's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

To find the missed dependency use the Dependency Walker. Open your DDL and it will show you all DDLs it depends on. It will show you also which one could not be found on the current systen.

http://www.dependencywalker.com/